# 301 redirect urls with specific string for .htaccess

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect

I'm new to this coding. I've searched all over for ways to do this but I have not come up with a working solution. I'm not even sure if I am looking for the correct thing. I've been looking at query_string, but am stumped.

Basically, I would like to 301 redirect a URL such as http://domain.com/page12345.html to http://domain.com/page23456.html Where the "page12345" may read any digits and any number of digits. All pages in that format would redirect to a set page.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the "set page"? Is it literally `page23456.html`?

Answer (score 0):

This rule should redirect any request that matches /page*.html where * is any combination of numeric characters

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/page([0-9]+)\.html http://domain.com/page23456.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks.. but I should have specified that it should only redirect if it follows the /page([0-9]+).html format.

Comment: The regex you have would work, I modified the above example to use with your constraints.

Comment: I had no luck with that code unfortunately.. let me know what you think.

Comment: That should work, I just double checked it - although I tested it directly in httpd.conf. For .htaccess, mod-rewrite requires that the server have the following options set: Allow-Override FileInfo as per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride. Do you know if you have that permission?